# Checkbox inserts text into textarea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text, checkbox, textarea

I am trying to do something really simple using only Javascript (not JQuery). 
Basically, I want to use a checkbox to toggle the text in a textarea. So if the checkbox is unchecked I want it to say "Hello" in the textarea. If the checkbox is checked, the textarea should say "Goodbye". 
I'm just getting started with Javascript, so any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Here is the code:

```
var myswitch = document.getElementsByTagName("myonoffswitch");
var mytextarea= document.getElementsByTagName("mytextarea");
myswitch.onchange = function(){
      if(this.checked){
        mytextarea.value = "Hello"
      }else{
        mytextarea.value = "Goodbye"
    }
}
```

Comment: which tag is this in HTML `myonoffswitch` & `mytextarea` ? Post your markup as well that'll help.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. They actually all work; I guess there are a lot of ways to do this in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If your controls are in a form, you can do something really simple like:

```
<form>
  <textarea name="ta"></textarea>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="
    this.form.ta.value = this.checked? 'Hello':'Goodbye';
  ">
</form>
```

Note that using the change event with a checkbox means that in some browsers, the event won't be dispatched until the checkbox loses focus, so better to use the click event.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `document.getElementById` instead of `getElementsByTagName`

I can't tell from your code snippet if you've wrapped your code in an `onload` function. This is required in situations where your DOM elements are not loaded in the HTML at the time your javascript is running

Here's an example

```
window.onload = function () {
    var myswitch = document.getElementById("myonoffswitch");
    var mytextarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    myswitch.onchange = function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            mytextarea.value = "Hello";
        } else {
            mytextarea.value = "Goodbye";
        }
    }
    //code here
}
```

And a fiddle is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/C4jVG/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something. This should work for you

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">Switch</input>
<textarea id="mytextarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Javascript

```
function fillText() {
        var myswitch = document.getElementById("myonoffswitch");
        var mytextarea= document.getElementById("mytextarea");
        myswitch.onchange = function(){
            if(this.checked){
                mytextarea.value = "Hello"
            }else{
                mytextarea.value = "Goodbye"
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = fillText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try replacing `getElementsByTagName` in your code with `getElementById` this will solve your problem.